# Compute index for leafs in a tree structure

Tags: c++, data-structures, binary-tree

Given a tree (binary) structure, with depth N. Is it possible to compute some lookup index for mapping leaf nodes.

Each node knows its parent, and its childs(left and right) if its not a leaf.

My Idea was something like saying rootnode is index 0, then left:1,left:left:2, left:left:left:3, left:left:right:4, left:right:left:5,left:right:right:6,right:7,right:left:8  e.g.

So given a leaf node, how can i compute the index smartest.

Other solutions are accepted also, if its smarter to give the leafs indexes from 0,1...L, where L is the number of leafs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to represent a tree in an array, the simplest is to take the layers of tree one at a time.

```
      0
     / \
    /   \
   1     2       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
  / \   / \
 3   4 5   6
```

This way, finding the parent is simply: `(index-1)/2`. And finding the two children is just `2*index` and `2*index + 1`.

Comment: My tree are generated in a extern lib. It does so recursive, computing left and then right. I then want to compute a map for faster finding the leaf node. So when passed a leaf node, i need to find its index by asking what its parents are.  I want to do this because its faster to iterate N steps over a nodes parents, than iterate over all nodes in the tree to find the node. Reason is that i need to store some additional information linked to the leaf nodes and i cant extend the classes.

Answer (score 0):

In my Tree structure (Quadtree and Octree) I am using a binary representation of the indexes of each node. e.g. 32 bit (for max 32 level) for each dimension.
So I can compute the complete index (or path) of a leaf by the formula

path.x = (unsigned int)(leaf.position.x * pow(2,32));

leaf.position.x musst be in a range from 0...1

The only constraint (I think) for this method is that the data you are storing musst be in a specific range, so that you can devide it by your area size.
If this is possible for your usecase read more at
[Simple and Efﬁcient Traversal Methods for
Quadtrees and Octrees](http://www.merl.com/reports/docs/TR2002-41.pdf)

Comment: I did think of making use of bits for the path, but my trees are somewhat deeper than 32 bits. For now i just computed the index from iterating left first and then right, and giving them index++ when a new leaf is reached.